# UIScrollview reloading multiple controls

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollview` containing 10 (number may vary) different custom controls, when user tap on a button I need to add one more control to the `Scrollview` at the 7th position. I am doing this by reloading all the controls again, but I don't think this is the right way to do so. Also some times I am getting memory warning. Can any one, who has experienced with this before, suggest a perfect way to implement this one?

Comment: please provide code..

Comment: Using a UITableView is not feasible?

Comment: there several uitableviews and buttons in the same scrollview

Comment: Could you provide code and screen shot as that would be much clear for us to understand your need.

Comment: better to use UITableView. otherwise add controls in one array and when you are reload the scrollview take the controls from the array. so controls will be alloc/init only for one time.

Comment: This is a survey questionaire with multiple questions, First the view shows 10 questions and if the answer to first question is yes  then show 11 questions, the additional question should be added as the second one